# How to display form output in the same page by hiding the form

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I need some help here please. I am stuck on some parts of the javascript.

What I need to do is make a form and display custom greeting cards. We are allowed to use pictures as cards (set them as background for the output). The form should let the user enter some customization information such as the name of the recipient, colour information, etc. And it also lets them add stickers of the some of the famous cartoon characters. There should be a button that, when they hit it, hides the form (by changing the CSS visibility or display property of the corresponding element) and shows a card that incorporates the text and other configuration details they entered.

What I am stuck with now is how to set background pictures as per their selection of the greeting card and characters (using "if else statements" or switch cases). Also I need to set the text and stickers at certain point on the background picture.

Your time and help provided is much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Following is my Java Script, CSS and HTML code:

```js
 < script >
   function selectAll() {
     for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[0]['charac'].length - 1; i++)
       document.forms[0]['charac'][i].checked = document.forms[0]['charac'][5].checked;
   }
 document.forms[0]['charac'][5].addEventListener('click', selectAll);

 //    function showOutput() {
 //        var a = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
 //        var b = document.getElementById("txtName1").value;
 //        var c = document.getElementById("content-field").value;

 //        document.writeln(a + "<br><br> " + b + "<br><br> " + c);
 //        document.getElementById("formOutput").innerHTML = "This is how your card looks" + a + " " + b + " " + c;
 //         document.getElementById("formCard").style.backgroundImage="url('birthday-card.jpg')";
 //                            }

 function myCard() {
     var a = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
     var b = document.getElementById("txtName1").value;
     var c = document.getElementById("content-field").value;
     //        document.getElementById("formOutput").style.backgroundImage="url('birthday-card.jpg')";

     var selected;
     if (document.forms[0][9].checked == true) {
       document.body.style.backgroundImage = url('birthday-card.jpg');
       document.getElementById("formOutput").innerHTML = a + "<br><br> " + b + "<br><br> " + c;
     } else
     if (document.forms[0][10].checked == true) {
       document.body.style.backgroundImage = url('valentine-card.jpg');
       document.getElementById("formOutput").innerHTML = a + "<br><br> " + b + "<br><br> " + c;
     } else
     if (document.forms[0][11].checked == true) {
       document.body.style.backgroundImage = url('valentine-card.jpg');
       document.getElementById("formOutput").innerHTML = a + "<br><br> " + b + "<br><br> " + c;
     } else
     if (document.forms[0][12].checked == true) {
       document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('valentine-card.jpg')";
       //                document.getElementById("formOutput").innerHTML ="name";
     } else
     if (selected == document.forms[0][13]) {
       document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('valentine-card.jpg')";
       //                document.getElementById("formOutput").innerHTML ="name";
     } else
     if (selected == document.forms[0][14]) {
       document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('valentine-card.jpg')";
       //                document.getElementById("formOutput").innerHTML ="name";
     } else
     if (selected == document.forms[0][15]) {
       document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('valentine-card.jpg')";
       //                document.getElementById("formOutput").innerHTML ="name";
     }
   }
   //        document.forms[0][24].addEventListener('click', showOutput);
   < /script>
```

```css
<style> #formOutput {
  background-image: url("blank-card1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align: center;
}
table {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
table td {
  height: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Generate a Greeting Card</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='formOutput'>
    <h3>Fill out the following information and select a card to view how it looks.</h3>

    <form id="formCard" action="">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal information:</legend>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="txtName">Your Name<span style="color:red">*</span>
              </label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id="txtName" name="name" value="name" required/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="txtName1">Your Family Member's
                <br>OR Friend's Name<span style="color:red">*</span>
              </label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id="txtName1" name="name1" value="Family/Friend Name" required/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="txtAddress">Address</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id="txtAddress" name="address" value=" ">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="postalCode">Postal Code<span style="color:red">*</span>
              </label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id="postalCode" name="postalcode" value=" " required/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Province<span style="color:red">*</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <select id="selProvince" name="province" required>
                <option value="" selected>Please select...</option>
                <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
                <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
                <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
                <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
                <option value="NFL">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
                <option value="NW">Northwest Territories</option>
                <option value="NS">Nova Scotia</option>
                <option value="NU">Nunavut</option>
                <option value="ON">Ontario</option>
                <option value="PEI">Prince Edward Island</option>
                <option value="QC">Quebec</option>
                <option value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
                <option value="YK">Yukon</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="txtPhone">Phone<span style="color:red">*</span>
              </label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id="txtPhone" name="phone" value=" " required/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label for="txtEmail">Email<span style="color:red">*</span>
              </label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id="txtEmail" name="email" required/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Would you like to send it
              <br>via email or mail<span style="color:red" required>*</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="route" value="m" />Mail</label>
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="route" value="e" />Email</label>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Type of Greeting Card:<span style="color:red">*</span>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
            </td>
            <td>
              <br>
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="card" id="birthday" value="bd" />Birthday</label>
              <br>
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="card" id="valentine" value="vd" />Valentines Day</label>
              <br>
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="card" id="friendship" value="frd" />Friendship Day</label>
              <br>
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="card" id="mother" value="md" />Mother's Day</label>
              <br>
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="card" id="father" value="fad" />Father's Day</label>
              <br>
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="card" id="newYear" value="nyd" />New Year's Day</label>
              <br>
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="card" id="christmas" value="cd" />Christmas Day</label>
              <br>
              <br>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Choose the person's
              <br>Favourite cartoon charcters:<span style="color:red">*</span>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <br>
            </td>
            <td>
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="charac" value="mickeyMouse" checked/>Mickey Mouse &amp; Clubhouse</label>
              <br>
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="charac" value="scoobyDoo" />Scooby Doo</label>
              <br>
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="charac" value="tomJerry" />Tom &amp; Jerry</label>
              <br>
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="charac" value="tweetiePie" />Tweetie Pie</label>
              <br>
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="charac" value="donaldDuck" />Donald Duck</label>
              <br>
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="charac" value="selectAll" />Select All</label>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Choose a colour for the
              <br>text on the card:</td>
            <!--color code from w3schools.org-->
            <td>
              <input type="color" id="html5colorpicker" onchange="clickColor(0, -1, -1, 5)" value="#ff0000" style="width:85%;">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label>Content</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <textarea id="content-field" cols="20" rows="2" value="" placeholder="Write them a personal message..."></textarea>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Choose an image to put on
              <br>the card to make it special.</td>
            <td>
              <label>
                <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
              </label>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
              <br>
              <br>
              <input type="button" onclick="myCard(); return false" value="SEND" />&nbsp;
              <input type="reset" value="CLEAR" />
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Question title doesn't really match what you ask inside. Also, a fiddle or a dev page with real url paths would be more useful than a code snippet. Interesting question though as I have an ecard system running on my website. When user selects from a dropdown my script adds classes to specific elements, with background image, color, etc. stored in css.

Comment: thanks but that doesn't answer my question. If you could help me with this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, give some more info on what user interaction will hide your form. Also, your mycard function fills #formOutput with new content. Your form, being a child of #formOutput, will be completely wiped. And, do you want to use pure JS only, or can it use jQuery as well?

Comment: Also, where's the button that will hide the form?

Comment: I can only use javaScript and it is the "SEND" button that would hide the form.

Comment: You talk of "we".... is this a study project or something? Do you need to traverse the form with document.forms[] etc or was that your own idea? As quite frankly I'm not sure how to do that... I'm using jQuery all the time for targeting elements. I can do it a bit different with JS, so let me know and I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I am talking about our class. I am a student and this is an assignment. I have figured out how to do this part but am stuck on how place text at certain points on the page. I need to do it using pixels.

Thanks for your help and time thus far, Yezzz. If you could please help me with this it would be of great help. 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will try... do you need to use document.forms[ index ]  as part of the assignment or was that your own idea?

Comment: Also, was the form given to you and you can't change it, or did you create it yourself? Need to know about any other imposed limitations before I start hacking away.

Comment: Do you want to only hide the form (for a preview) or really destroy it (as that's what your script is doing when setting innerHTML.

Comment: i have to just simply hide it

Comment: and then a button to bring the form back in view?

Comment: no we can just refresh the page

Comment: haha ok then I'll keep it like that... posting a partial solution in a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first off: don't do that index numbering to target elements. If another form gets added to a page, or some inputs added to the form it means trouble, having to redo all the numbers. Use ID's, classnames, etc. which also makes things more readable and easier to debug. Same for the vars: i,x is great for small loops, but a meaningful var name is easier to debug. Well, end of teacher mode hahaa. I learned that I should work on my vanilla js :)

TIP! I did not use this, but you can easily target elements in js with css paths using [querySelector](http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector)!

Anyway, I changed some things in your script, used an array for images instead of a switch, and created a loop for getting the BG image. Just adjust the img names and the path (uncomment line 35). Didn't know what you wanted with the text (and stickers???) so all I did was clean up and fixed some bugs. Have a look:

```
//
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ovhq5v25

Comment: Thank you for your help yezz. Appreciate it